# Veracrypt exFat inside Kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, mount, kubernetes, veracrypt, exfat

I have a working solution to run this veracrypt command inside a pod:
`veracrypt --text --quick --non-interactive --create /media/vera --volume-type normal --size 200M --password 123456 --hash SHA-512 --encryption AES --filesystem exFat --force`

The related settings in the deployment yml:

```yml
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
          - SYS_ADMIN
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dev
          mountPath: /dev
      volumes:
      - name: dev
        hostPath:
          path: /dev
```

My current goal is to remove the host `/dev` mount and the `privileged: true` field to improve security.

I've found a git repository called [smarter-device-manager](https://gitlab.com/arm-research/smarter/smarter-device-manager) and it provides a way to access host devices inside the container by describing the required devices in the resource request/limit section of deployment yml file.

Right now the pod has the `SYS_ADMIN` capability, the `fuse`, `loop-control`, `loop[0-7]` and `mapper/control` devices mounted by the smarter-device-manager and the `container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/<container_name>: unconfined` annotation.

The result of the veracrypt command above:

```
Done: 100.000% Speed: 5.2 MiB/s Left: 0s
Error: device-mapper: create ioctl on veracrypt1  failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed.
```

`dmsetup ls` lists a `veracrypt1` device, and after executing `dmsetup remove veracrypt1` it is not on the list anymore.
Executing the veracrypt command again results in this:

```
Done: 100.000% Speed: 5.2 MiB/s Left: 0s
Error: No such file or directory
/dev/mapper/veracrypt1
```

`dmsetup ls` shows the `veracrypt1` device again and executing the veracrypt command again results in  the same way as before. (`Error: device-mapper: create ioctl on veracrypt1  failed`)

`ls /dev/mapper/` in this container does not show the `veracrypt1` device, but it shows up in the container with mounted `/dev` and `privileged: true`.

The veracrypt command with `--filesystem Fat` instead of `--filesystem exFat` can be executed successfully.

Kubernetes node kernel version is 4.4.0-190-generic
Veracrypt version is 1.24-Update4

What other devices or capabilities or anything else does the container need to execute the example command successfully?

Any help would be highly appreciated.